# Group Items By Property in Swift 4

Tags: swift

My data source is

> {"events": [{"name":"event
>   foo","date":"2018-07-21","time":"7:00","am_or_pm":"PM","day":"Saturday","description":"test
>   "}, {"name":"event
>   bar","date":"2018-07-21","time":"7:00","am_or_pm":"PM","day":"Saturday","description":"test2"},
>   {"name":"event
>   foobar","date":"2018-07-21","time":"11:00","am_or_pm":"PM","day":"Saturday","description":"test3"}]}

I have tried dictionary/arrays, but not really getting close to my wanted result.

Pulling out data into an array:

```
var times = ["9:00","9:00","11:00"]

var names = ["event foo","event bar","event foobar"]
```

Desired output:

```
["9:00", "11:00"]

[["event foo", "event bar"], ["event foobar"]]
```

Any pointers to do this in Swift is appreciated. My end result is to hope to section a uitableview grouped by time.

Comment: Holy documentation, Batman! https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init

Comment: Your declaration `var events ... ` does not work anyway because dictionary keys must be unique.

Comment: You should at least attempt some code, we can try to help you if you get stuck. If you don't know the language enough, tell us what algorithm you thought of and we can go from there.

Comment: @Cristik, posted the direction I was going.

Comment: @Matt I saw that, couldn't sort through my problem with it though.

Comment: @vadian, thank you, fixed.

Comment: Dan, unrelated to your question here, if you can, I might suggest re-factoring your web service to return the date, time, and the am/pm designation as a single ISO 8601 date string.  It will simplify your parsing, and will minimize localization issues. Just a thought...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using Swift 4, you can use `reduce(into:)` and the `default` value for subscript operator:

```
guard
    let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: [Any]],
    let events = json["events"] as? [[String: String]] else {
        return
}

let results = events.reduce(into: [String: [String]]()) { result, value in
    guard let time = value["time"], let name = value["name"] else { return }
    result[time, default: []].append(name)
}
```

That results in a dictionary:

> ["11:00": ["event foobar"], "7:00": ["event foo", "event bar"]]

---

Or, as Vadian suggested, you can use `Dictionary(grouping:,by:)`, but then you have to `map` it if you only want your `name` values, resulting in an array of tuples:

```
let results = Dictionary(grouping: events, by: { $0["time"]! })
    .map { ($0.key, $0.value.map { $0["name"]! })}
```

> [("11:00", ["event foobar"]), ("7:00", ["event foo", "event bar"])]

---

Personally, like Vadian suggested, I'd be inclined to combine `date`, `time`, and `am_or_pm` to build a full `Date` object and use one of the above patterns. E.g.:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

// if date/time values are in GMT, uncomment the following line:
//
// formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let results = events.reduce(into: [Date: [String]]()) { result, value in
    guard
        let timeString = value["time"],
        let dateString = value["date"],
        let amPm = value["am_or_pm"],
        let date = formatter.date(from: dateString + " " + timeString + " " + amPm),
        let name = value["name"] else { return }
    result[date, default: []].append(name)
}
```

or

```
let results = Dictionary(grouping: events, by: { dictionary -> Date in
    let string = dictionary["date"]! + " " + dictionary["time"]! + " " + dictionary["am_or_pm"]!
    return formatter.date(from: string)!
})
    .map { ($0.key, $0.value.map { $0["name"]! })}
```

Or, if the web service returned a single ISO 8601/RFC 3339 string representation of the date, time, and am/pm in the JSON, this could be simplified further.

Comment: Rob, thank you so much! `reduce(into:)` was exactly what I needed to simplifiy this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to decode the JSON with `Decodable` and create a full date from the *components*. Then use `Dictionary(grouping:by:`) to group the array.

First create a `DateFormatter` (uncomment the time zone line if you need absolute UTC dates)

```
let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    // formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    return formatter
}()
```

Create two structs for the root element and the `events` array. A custom initializer creates the `Date` instance

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let events : [Event]
}

struct Event : Decodable {
    let date : Date
    let name, description : String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, date, time, am_or_pm, description}

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        let datePortion = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        let timePortion = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .time)
        let ampm = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .am_or_pm)
        let dateString = "\(datePortion) \(timePortion) \(ampm)"
        guard let fullDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .date,
                                                   in: container,
                                                   debugDescription: "Date cannot be created")
        }
        date = fullDate
    }
}
```

Decode the JSON and group the array

```
let jsonString = """
{"events": [{"name":"event foo","date":"2018-07-21","time":"7:00","am_or_pm":"PM","day":"Saturday","description":"test "}, {"name":"event bar","date":"2018-07-21","time":"7:00","am_or_pm":"PM","day":"Saturday","description":"test2"}, {"name":"event foobar","date":"2018-07-21","time":"11:00","am_or_pm":"PM","day":"Saturday","description":"test3"}]}
"""

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: result.events, by: { $0.date})
    print(grouped)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Comment: This answers the broader question of "what is the right way to do this". Good answer (+1). Custom objects are invariably better in the long run.